# How to add custom PHP pages to Odoo Community 12?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, odoo-12

How can I use the login page of Odoo Community (which is already all setup and working on my own server) and show my custom php webpages after login to specific users?

Comment: Without rewriting them to QWeb, I suppose. What's your specific problem? The session?

Comment: @AdanCortes I just want to use the login system of odoo since that is supposedly already secure and has the database with login details. Then I want to redirect/show him another webapplication depending upon the username.

Comment: In that case, you're trying to kill flies with a tank. You better use Google's or Facebook Single Sign On APIs

Comment: @AdanCortes I am already using odoo for other users. And I have sensitive data so can't use those.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. SSO will not expose sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Write a controller (for reference, see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/http.html#controllers).

- Use the `auth='user'` parameter so if someone who is not logged in goes directly to `/some_url` he/she will be asked to log in first.
- Return a redirect (see https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/utils/#werkzeug.utils.redirect)

The controller may look something like:

```
from odoo import http
import werkzeug

class MyController(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/some_url', auth='user')
    def handler(self):
        # set new_url
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect(new_url, code=307)
```

Disclaimer: This method has a serious drawback, which is you need to make sure your  PHP validates the session token with Odoo before serving pages.